# How to filter data with displaytag?

Tags: java, jsp, filter, jstl, displaytag

Is it anyhow possible to filter data with display tag? I want to filter data by date column, and that by providing lower and upper date limits.

EDIT:
I have two input fields. One for first date value, and another one for second date value. After submitting those, I want table data to display rows with dates between the two specified date values.

Comment: Filter data in what sense ? Do you want to sort the table ? Do you want to display any specific data at specific position ? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter from Java class before pass the values on display tag.

Comment: I'm using jstl sql for getting data from database. Is than the best course of action to just write sql query with specifying directly bordering date values inside where clause?